# R: How to create a vector of functions?

Tags: r

I would like to create a vector of functions using a two agruments function 'func', for instance this one:

```
func = function(number, coefficient) {  
    return(coefficient*number)  
}
```

here is how I create the vector of functions:

```
vector_of_functions = NULL  
for (i in 1:4) {  
vector_of_functions = c(vector_of_functions,
    function(number) func(number=number, coefficient=i))  
}
```

My issue is that all functions that compose my vector are the same, even if they have been created using different i through the loop. It seams that they are evaluated using the last value of i (which is here a global variable).

Anybody has an idea?

Thanks

Comment: I continue here as I am new user and the forum blocks my question if it contains too many lines of code apparently....

Comment: How many lines of code do you have? Add that is important for us to answer.

Comment: The error I get is "as new user you cannot post more than one hyperlink". But I dont see any hyperlink in my question

Comment: I managed to edit my question to add the end. Thanks

Comment: The "i" isn't being evaluated during the function definition, only during function execution - but can you tell us what you are trying to accomplish? Your example strikes me as very odd

Comment: Answer appeared here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3836/how-to-create-a-vector-of-functions . Please don't cross-post in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved using an eval-parse construct, although I strongly advice you **not** to use this construct. It often causes more problems than anything else. But I couldn't get a decent do.call way of doing it.

```
vector_of_functions = NULL
for (i in 1:4) {
vector_of_functions = c(vector_of_functions,
  eval(parse(text=paste("function(number) func(number=number, coefficient=",i,")"))))
}
```

Reason is as Aaron explained: everything within the function definition is taken as is until the function evaluation.

Small remark: this is especially a **list** of functions, and not a vector. It's impossible to have a vector of type "function". It's also absolutely useless, as you have to select the function using the index [[]] before you can use it. Then I'd just add the argument instead of defining a function for every possible value of one of the arguments.

So what you want to achieve is unclear, but if you want to apply func with different coefficients, I wonder why you don't simply do:

```
> x <- c(10,20,30)
> sapply(1:4,function(y)func(number=x,coefficient=y))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   10   20   30   40
[2,]   20   40   60   80
[3,]   30   60   90  120
```

---

A variation on the theme by Marek (avoiding the parsing):

```
vector_of_functions = NULL
for (i in 1:4) {
vector_of_functions = c(vector_of_functions,
  eval(substitute(function(number) func(number=number, coefficient=i),list(i=i))))
}
```

The 1L etc. you get, just indicate they're exact integers (that take less memory space).

Comment: Instead of `parse(text(` thing better use `substitute`: `eval(substitute(function(number) func(number=number, coefficient=i),list(i=i)))`

Comment: Anyway it is list so line in loop can be changed to: vector_of_functions[[i]] =  eval(substitute(function(number) func(number=number, coefficient=i),list(i=i)))

Answer (score 4):

You can "attach" the value of `i` to each function by redefining `i` in its own local environment (conveniently created by the function, `local` in R). The resulting function with data "attached" is called a 'closure'.

```
> vector_of_functions = NULL  
> for (i in 1:4) {  
+ vector_of_functions = c(vector_of_functions,
+     local({i <- i;function(number) func(number=number, coefficient=i)}))
+ }
> vector_of_functions[[1]](1)
[1] 1
> vector_of_functions[[2]](1)
[1] 2
> vector_of_functions[[3]](1)
[1] 3
> vector_of_functions[[4]](1)
[1] 4
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to lazy evaluation, the 'i' variable is not being evaluted at each step, so when you call the function it uses the last value.  The force function was created to force the evaluation in cases like this (there is an example on the help page for ?force that is very similar to your question).